# Remove text from integer fields in csv-files

Tags: regex, text, csv, sed, integer

I have a large .csv file that looks like this

```
19186;1964;F;001;;;;19000101;21000101;20110630
19187;1972;M;001;MMag. Dr.;;;19000101;21000101;20110630
19190;1936;F;999;3;;;19000101;21000101;20110630
```

Everytime the 5th value is *not an integer <10* (not 0-9) it should be removed. So the result should look like this

```
19186;1964;F;001;;;;19000101;21000101;20110630
19187;1972;M;001;;;;19000101;21000101;20110630
19190;1936;F;999;3;;;19000101;21000101;20110630
```

how can this be done with `sed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(([^;]*;){4})[^;0-9]+/\1/' file
```

Comment: cool. but this wouldn't go together with my existing sed command (which is not using the argument `-r`). Can this be done without extended regexp?

Comment: got it: `sed 's/\(\([^;]*;\)\{4\}\)[^;0-9]\+/\1/g' file`

Answer (score 3):

If you can use `awk` instead, this would be cleaner to read than a `sed` solution, I think:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}
     {if (($5 >= 10) || ($5 < 0) || ($5 % 1 != 0)) {$5=""} print}' in_file
```

*Input:*

```
19186;1964;F;001;;;;19000101;21000101;20110630
19187;1972;M;001;MMag. Dr.;;;19000101;21000101;20110630
19190;1936;F;999;3;;;19000101;21000101;20110630
19190;1936;F;999;-3;;;19000101;21000101;20110630
19190;1936;F;999;3.5;;;19000101;21000101;20110630
19190;1936;F;999;10;;;19000101;21000101;20110630
```

*Output:*

```
19186;1964;F;001;;;;19000101;21000101;20110630
19187;1972;M;001;;;;19000101;21000101;20110630
19190;1936;F;999;3;;;19000101;21000101;20110630
19190;1936;F;999;;;;19000101;21000101;20110630
19190;1936;F;999;;;;19000101;21000101;20110630
19190;1936;F;999;;;;19000101;21000101;20110630
```

**Explanation:**

- `awk`: invoke the awk command
- `'...'`: provide the instructions to awk inside single quotes
- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}`: before reading input, tell `awk` to use `;` as delimiters for both input and output (FS stands for Field Separator, OFS stands for Output Field Separator)
- `{if (($5 >= 10) || ($5 < 0) || ($5 % 1 != 0)) {$5=""}`: If the 5th field is not between `0-9`, or is not an integer, set that field to the empty string.
- `print`: print the (possibly) modified line.
- `in_file`: specify "in_file" as input file to your `awk` script
- Optionally, add `> out_file` to the end of the above script to redirect output to a file instead of `stdout`

**Alternatively:** for a cleaner & more robust solution, see Ed's answer.

Comment: That will fail for some strings. Try it with $5 set to "1-foo".

Comment: @EdMorton Ah, I think I see what the problem is: `awk` must consider `1-foo` as an expression and it evaluates into `1-0=1`. I played around with different cases: `1:foo` and `1foo` both work correctly; and `5+foo+6` (which is 11) will also get the 5th field removed. This is pretty cool =) TIL.

Comment: No. Try it with "1 MMag Dr.". :-)

Comment: See "String Type Versus Numeric Type" under http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Typing-and-Comparison for a big hint.

Comment: np. As you've probably realized by now the issue is that when $5 is non-numeric you're doing string comparisons, not numeric comparisons, and those are done char-by-char left-to-right so there are some characters X for which the string "1X" is less than the string "10" but any string starting with "1" is always greater than the string "0". Then you have an arithmetic operation (%) which chops off the num-numeric tail of $5 so "1X" becomes "1" before the comparison with 0.

Comment: Thanks, however, I would like to stick to `sed` as I already have a lot of manipulations done in `sed` - i want to append my existing command

Answer (score 3):

You could do it in sed but it's simpler with awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} $5!~/^[0-9]$/{$5=""} 1' file
```